# Damage to low profile tire upon dismounting

Tags: ford, tires, damage

I took my car to get the summer tires changed out to the winter tires. Upon dismounting of my tires one tire ended up with a tear at the bead. The technician said the damage was not caused by him dismounting the tire, but from when the previous technician mounted the tire.  The technician is saying the tire is not safe to be mounted again and I need a new tire.  I had ZERO trouble with the tire until they dismounted it.

I drive a Ford Edge Sport that runs 21" low profile tires. I understand the risk for damage is higher with these low profile tires.

Can you please help me understand the process of unmounting a low profile tire and the types of damage that could occur during this process?
Also if you can help me to understand whether the damage could have been pre-existing? Is it possible to drive on a tire for the past 6 months and have no issues, yet there was damage?

Thank you!

Comment: I have two sets of rims, one for summer and one for winter so avoiding such issues...

Comment: Yes, I just bought this vehicle and haven't gotten the 2nd set of rims yet. I realize that alleviates all of these issues. Thank you.

Comment: If the damage was on the bead where it presses against the rim, I can't see how it could have been caused by anyone but them, unless the last technition damaged it, never told you, and somehow it held air the entire time you used it.

Comment: The last technician was the dealer/manufacturer.  It is a new vehicle.

Comment: Small claims court. My guess they will settle before embarrassing themselves. Its all about the question “Which is more likely...?”